# HDMI over USB-C multiport adapter works, SOMETIMES!

Tags: hdmi, external-monitor, usb-c

Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 7320

The laptop has an HDMI port on board, which works fine. The multiport adapter also works fine for USB loop through, and SSD cards.

But when I connect a display to the HDMI port of the adapter, that usually does not work in Ubuntu.

Usually. Because once in a blue moon, it does work.

Some things to consider:

- The displays and cables are fine, as I can test them with the onboard HDMI port
- The adapter is fine, because via dual boot in Windows, the HDMI connector consistently works.
- The problem existed on 20.04 and 21.04 as well
- I tried booting up fresh with minimal hardware attached, booting with only the HDMI via adapter, and various other hardware subsets. All to no avail.
- xrandr shows just the main display (and on board hdmi port when connected)

My gut feeling is that there's a randomized aspect to hardware detection in the Ubuntu kernel, which due to timing issues, usually results in an order of things that leads to the HDMI port not being recognized (correctly), and then discarded as hardware device.

What can I do to move this forward?

Comment: Solution. 

When I said, minimal hardware, I meant attached to the laptop.

However, the screens themselves are also USB-capable, and I had mouse, keyboard, and external HDD attached. Plus, both screen were connected in series to the external adapter.

Removing all the peripherals from the screens solved my problem. I was able to reconnect them without issue.

Is it possible that the peripherals interfered with the readings the HDMI port received? Perhaps a power surge due to everything turning on at once, and the HDMI port therefore disconnecting as a safety precaution?